# How to remove leading zero/zeros in azure logic app for variables?

Tags: azure, logic, azure-logic-apps

Removing the first number if it's 0 or 000

eg1- 000123400 è Convert the data to search -123400

eg2 -0001234 è Convert the data to search - 1234

Comment: If the string is always only numeric, you could just parse it to int, that should do the trick https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#int

Comment: yes, the id = 0456 is always numeric. how to remove the first number if its start with '0'  or '00' or maybe multiple time zeroes

Comment: for example use a set-variable block and there use the int() function that I have linked above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What silent said in the comments is right, his design process is like this:

[image]