# Remove leading zeros from a string using functions available in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Is there any logic to remove leading zeros from an alphanumeric string using functions available in logic app in a single step

Comment: You could use a regex (inline code) but it requires having an integration account. a loop would do the trick but doesnt sounds like a proper solution tho...

Comment: Not with a single step. But otherwise, you can refer to this solutionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684311/how-to-remove-leading-zero-zeros-in-azure-logic-app-for-variables

Comment: I did this by using javascript connector in my logic app passing my input string as dynamic content and replaced the leading zeros by using regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got the fix

Here is the screenshot of my logic app
[image]

I'm passing alphanumeric string from HTTP request and Here is the compose function that worked for me

```
substring(triggerBody(),indexOf(triggerBody(),first(replace(triggerBody(),'0',''))))
```